# Drag a node multiple times with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag a rectangle to a VBox and then drag it again from inside the VBox.
If the rectangle is dropped anywhere outside of the target VBox, then it should revert its position back to where it belonged: if it was a child of the left VBox, then reset it back inside of it; if it was a child of the right VBox, reset it back inside of the right VBox.
The first part works fine, I can drag it to the VBox and add it as a child. The second part is where I'm having a problem.

```java
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragNodeMultipleTimes extends Application {
    private Disk sourceDisk = new Disk();
    private VBox targetVBox = new VBox();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Build the UI
        GridPane root = getUI();

        // Add the event handlers
        this.addEventHandlers();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private GridPane getUI() {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        VBox sourceVBox = new VBox();

        sourceDisk.setWidth(90);
        sourceDisk.setHeight(20);

        sourceVBox.setStyle(" -fx-border-color:red; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-style: solid;");
        targetVBox.setStyle(" -fx-border-color:green; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-style: solid;");

        sourceVBox.getChildren().add(sourceDisk);
        targetVBox.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(200, 20));

        pane.setHgap(200);
        pane.addColumn(0, sourceVBox);
        pane.addColumn(1, targetVBox);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(200, 100, 200, 100));

        return pane;
    }

    private void addEventHandlers() {
        sourceDisk.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            sourceDisk.setOrgSceneX(event.getSceneX());
            sourceDisk.setOrgSceneY(event.getSceneY());
            sourceDisk.setOrgTranslateX(sourceDisk.getTranslateX());
            sourceDisk.setOrgTranslateY(sourceDisk.getTranslateY());

            sourceDisk.setMouseTransparent(true);

            event.consume();
        });

        sourceDisk.setOnDragDetected(event -> sourceDisk.startFullDrag());

        sourceDisk.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - sourceDisk.getOrgSceneX();
            double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - sourceDisk.getOrgSceneY();
            double newTranslateX = sourceDisk.getOrgTranslateX() + offsetX;
            double newTranslateY = sourceDisk.getOrgTranslateY() + offsetY;

            sourceDisk.setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
            sourceDisk.setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
        });

        sourceDisk.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
            //reset the position of the disk
            sourceDisk.setTranslateX(0);
            sourceDisk.setTranslateY(0);

            sourceDisk.setMouseTransparent(false);
        });

        targetVBox.setOnMouseDragEntered(Event::consume);

        targetVBox.setOnMouseDragOver(event -> System.out.println("VBox: mouseDragOver"));

        targetVBox.setOnMouseDragReleased(event -> {
            ((VBox) (event.getSource())).getChildren().add(0, sourceDisk);

            //reset translate values
            sourceDisk.setTranslateX(0);
            sourceDisk.setTranslateY(0);

            sourceDisk.setMouseTransparent(false);
        });
    }

    private class Disk extends Rectangle {
        private double orgSceneX;
        private double orgSceneY;
        private double orgTranslateX;
        private double orgTranslateY;

        public double getOrgSceneX() {
            return orgSceneX;
        }

        public void setOrgSceneX(double orgSceneX) {
            this.orgSceneX = orgSceneX;
        }

        public double getOrgSceneY() {
            return orgSceneY;
        }

        public void setOrgSceneY(double orgSceneY) {
            this.orgSceneY = orgSceneY;
        }

        public double getOrgTranslateX() {
            return orgTranslateX;
        }

        public void setOrgTranslateX(double orgTranslateX) {
            this.orgTranslateX = orgTranslateX;
        }

        public double getOrgTranslateY() {
            return orgTranslateY;
        }

        public void setOrgTranslateY(double orgTranslateY) {
            this.orgTranslateY = orgTranslateY;
        }
    }
}
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:
1) Drag the left rectangle on top of the right one (inside the VBox)
2) Drag the newly added rectangle to a place outside of the VBox
3) Release the mouse button

The problem arises at step 2. What I'm expecting is that the VBox no longer gets any events from the mouse, since it left its boundary. This does not happen, as can be seen in the console output (the onMouseDragOver is still being called).
At step 3, an exception is thrown, but this happens because it tries to add the same rectangle back to the VBox.

What I'm expecting is that if I drag the rectangle outside of the right VBox and release the mouse, then the rectangle resets its position to be back inside the right VBox.

Basically, what I'm trying to figure out is how can it be that even though the cursor is not within the bounds of the VBox, it still receives MOUSE_DRAGGED events?
I'm also open to suggestions of other approaches to achieving this result.

Comment: Any Node you want to drop the rectangle in needs to have target event handlers. From what I can tell, you only have target event handlers on the `VBox`.

Comment: Also, `targetVBox.getChildren().add(0, sourceDisk)` should be something like `((Node)event.getSource()).getChildren().add(0, sourceDisk)`. <- code may not be `100% correct but the idea should be good.

Comment: I have edited my post in the attempt to make my intention more clear. I have also updated the event handler for the MOUSE_RELEASED and with your suggestion to replace the code for adding the child to the VBox. In short, I'm expecting that when I release the mouse anywhere outside of the 2 VBoxes, the rectangle goes back to its initial position (either in the left or the right VBox).

Comment: It should be a matter of adding the node back to its original VBox if the drag fails. I will look at this after my meeting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite certain but I've an assumption.
The Disk is added as a child of the VBox, as such it's seen like a part of it and the same events, which apply to the VBox apply to the Disk. So since the Disk is a part of the VBox now you're mouse is still in the VBox as you drag it's child

I think it's like this: If a child receives an event all parents receive it as well.

So you need to remove the Disk from the VBox as soon as it dragged outside.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your suggestion makes alot of sense and I have investigated this further. It appears that, when I click the disk, there is an event dispatch chain, and so the MOUSE_DRAGGED event goes through from the child node all the way up to the stage. In this case, the event will be 'heard' by both the disk and the VBox. However, I don't think I can remove the disk from the VBox when it is outside because the MOUSE_DRAG_EXITED only registers after the mouse is released. I also have the feeling that the mouse being transparent might be related to the issue. Any thoughts?